# Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found when hosting laravel 5.7 project on Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, web-hosting, laravel-5.7

I tried to host a laravel 5.7 application on cpanel but I have got a FatalErrorException "Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found" in "MyLaravelAppFolder/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php

In my composer.json, the required php version on my project is >= 7.0.0
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zezjo.jpg

And on server, I have created a phpinfo to check the Php version running on server:
imgur.com/a/pMHD6dZ

This is also the selected and the php version set as current on cpanel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/odSU2.jpg

And this is the error I obtained:
imgur.com/a/1JOxBsB

I have seen in many posts related with this problem that we should verify if json is checked (it is in my case), and the version should be >=7 for the Interface JsonSerializable and this is my version on server.

I do not know if I have missed something or I should configure something in relation with json on server?

Do not hesitate to demand any folder/file content if needed, I can comment with pictures like below.

Thanks.

Comment: Is JSON support active? In my cPanel I can enable/disable it under "Select PHP Version".

Comment: Yes bro, it is enabled. I have updated my php version to  and refresh and it worked. Do not know why (because it is indicated in documentation that JsonSerializable is working with php 7) but it is ok :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Laravel-related problem, but is an hosting's problem, then update your PHP version to 7.2 and check if JSON extension is enabled on your cPanel Hosting.